# How to use one-class SVM in matlab?

Tags: matlab, svm

I labeled some pixels of a picture as foreground and the rest of them are unlabeled yet. I want to use SVM and the labeled pixels's properties like color as SVM input to label the remaining pixels as background or foreground.
Is that possible with one-class as input? Or do I need some pixels labeled as background (two-class input)? 

Thanks in advance.
Edit: I found 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html 
 and 
 
http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/ 
For one-class SVM, but I dont know how to use it in matlab.

Comment: Do you have any pixels labelled as background?

Comment: Hi, no i dont, i just have information about forground.

Comment: LIBSVM has a MATLAB interface in the package

Comment: thanks alot , but can you help me how to use it please?

Comment: they have a readme in the zip.  it's pretty well-explained in there

Answer (score 8):

Setting up LIBSVM in Matlab is described in the `README` file contained in the official package, which can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm)

After you installed LIBSVM for your Matlab version, you can train an SVM model with the following:

```
matlab> model = svmtrain(training_label_vector, training_instance_matrix [, 'libsvm_options']);
```

Explanation (taken from the `README`)

```
 -training_label_vector:
        An m by 1 vector of training labels (type must be double).
    -training_instance_matrix:
        An m by n matrix of m training instances with n features.
        It can be dense or sparse (type must be double).
    -libsvm_options:
        A string of training options in the same format as that of LIBSVM.
```

The training options are:

```
-s svm_type : set type of SVM (default 0)
    0 -- C-SVC      (multi-class classification)
    1 -- nu-SVC     (multi-class classification)
    2 -- one-class SVM
    3 -- epsilon-SVR    (regression)
    4 -- nu-SVR     (regression)
-t kernel_type : set type of kernel function (default 2)
    0 -- linear: u'*v
    1 -- polynomial: (gamma*u'*v + coef0)^degree
    2 -- radial basis function: exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2)
    3 -- sigmoid: tanh(gamma*u'*v + coef0)
    4 -- precomputed kernel (kernel values in training_set_file)
-d degree : set degree in kernel function (default 3)
-g gamma : set gamma in kernel function (default 1/num_features)
-r coef0 : set coef0 in kernel function (default 0)
-c cost : set the parameter C of C-SVC, epsilon-SVR, and nu-SVR (default 1)
-n nu : set the parameter nu of nu-SVC, one-class SVM, and nu-SVR (default 0.5)
-p epsilon : set the epsilon in loss function of epsilon-SVR (default 0.1)
-m cachesize : set cache memory size in MB (default 100)
-e epsilon : set tolerance of termination criterion (default 0.001)
-h shrinking : whether to use the shrinking heuristics, 0 or 1 (default 1)
-b probability_estimates : whether to train a SVC or SVR model for probability estimates, 0 or 1 (default 0)
-wi weight : set the parameter C of class i to weight*C, for C-SVC (default 1)
-v n : n-fold cross validation mode
-q : quiet mode (no outputs)
```

If you want to train a One-Class-SVM (e.g. for Anomaly-Detection), you have to chose `-s 2` as an option.

In addition the parameter `nu` might be interesting in the tuning of your trained SVM as well as the appropriate `kernel parameters` for the selected kernel type (for example via grid-search).

To train a One-Class-SVM via LIBSVM you should only provide data, which belongs to the **under-represented** class.

Nevertheless for your kind of problem (since you are not going to do some kind of anomaly detection and features / samples are not rare), you should go for a normal two-class SVM.

Comment: I was looking for " -s 2" for setting svm type , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved using this simple code with Libsvm:

```
%train
[heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst] = libsvmread('heart3');
model = svmtrain(heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst, '-c 1 -g 0.07  -s 2');
%predict
[heart_scale_label2, heart_scale_inst2] = libsvmread('heart4');
[predict_label, accuracy, dec_values] = svmpredict(heart_scale_label2,
heart_scale_inst2, model); % test the training data
```

Comment: Hi, did you understand how to have "heart_scale_label2" as parameter for "predict"? I don't have labels, because I've to predict!